# How to calculate checksum for compiled shader code?

Tags: shader, bytecode, directx-11, checksum

I have compiled my pixel shader effects file(fx) to compiled shader object(cso) file i.e shader bytecode. I am able to compile it using following code:

```
D3DReadFileToBlob(L"xxx.cso", &pVSBlob);
```

I am able to execute it successfully but I want to modify few constants in shader bytecode. On modification of shader bytecode, my createPixelShader fails due to wrong checksum calculation.

How to calculate checksum of shader bytecode?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really well documented, but AMD has the function code in their shader utility library.

Mostly it is some md5 hash.

There is the source in their github repository [here](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/common-src-ShaderUtils/blob/master/DX10/DXBCChecksum.h)